# js vimeo video при клике откривается видео

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vimeo

за акцент извините
хочу сделать такое на вордпрессе
есть цикл которий возмет данние поста, там картинка название поста и есть мета бокс для урла вимео видеоа
на сайте нужно делать так с начала показивает все пости с картинками при клике на картинку будет откривать свое видео из вимео, все сделал кроме ето не могу сделать чтоб при клике на картинку откривал модал и там бил видео

Answer (score 2):

Можешь подключить jQuery-либу magnific-popup, там уже есть поддержка попапов с vimeo.

https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.popup-vimeo').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: false
    });
});
```